# Can someone please help me in drawing this RegionPlot with high precision?

Tags: plotting

Can someone who has access to Mathematica, please, help me in drawing this `RegionPlot` with high precision. (I used the basic plan of WolframCloud which I could not increase the precision). I do not want to use the result, I just want to know their shape, so, only a less quality image of the results can help me.

I want to know the following `RegionPlot` for different values of $a=\{0,\frac12,\frac13,\frac5 {13},8.13, 20.353\}$

````
a:=0;

RegionPlot[      (2 Sin[b x] Sin[b x-2 π x] Sin[a π-π x] Sin[a π+π x])>0     ,   {x,1000,1010}  ,{b,0,π}    ,  PlotPoints->100    ]

```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we also use `ContourPlot` and set `Contours->{0},ContourShading->{None,Blue}` instead of `RegionPlot`.

- a=0

```
fig1 = With[{a = 0}, 
  ContourPlot[
   2 Sin[b x] Sin[b x - 2 π x] Sin[a π - π x] Sin[
     a π + π x], {x, 100, 110}, {b, 0, π}, 
   Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> {None, Blue}, 
   ContourStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50,
    MaxRecursion -> 2]]
```

[image]

- a=5/13

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry, I miswrote the domain, I meant $\{x,1000,1010\}$ which will be simpler. Could you please use RegionPlot instead?

Comment: thanks again @cvgmt.

Comment: As my final request, may I ask you to please provide these two results for $\{{x,100,110}\}$ as well? Since it seems that for large values of $x$, the plots are not clear. @cvgmt

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and for your favor. @cvgmt

Comment: @charmin  I think `ContourPlot` is better than `RegionPlot` for high precision.